# Error: no 'void my server::incoming Connections(qintptr)' member function declared in class 'myserver'

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I want to write a simple client server program in Qt that server is multi thread but cause I am new in Qt ,I have problem in multi threading and also I get the following Error:no 'void my server::incoming Connections "(qintptr)" member function declared in class "myserver" .
Could you please help me, and if it possible say if you have better solution to writing multi thread server?
Here is my code:

"myserver.cpp:"

```
#include "myserver.h"
#include "mythread.h"


myserver::myserver(QObject *parent) :

QObject(parent)
{
}

void myserver::startserver()
{

int port = 1234;

if(s_server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, port))
  {
    qDebug() << "Could not start server";
  }
else
  {
    qDebug() << "Listening to port " ;
  }

}

void myserver::incomingConnections(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
  mythread *thread = new mythread(socketDescriptor,this);

  qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connecting...";

  connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

  thread->start();
  }


 void myserver::acceptConnection()

 {

  c_client = s_server.nextPendingConnection();

  connect(c_client,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(startRead()));

  qDebug() << " Connecting...";


  }
```

"mythread.cpp:"

```
  #include "mythread.h"
  #include "myserver.h"

  mythread::mythread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent) :

  QThread(parent)
 {
 this->socketDescriptor = ID;
 }


void mythread::run()
  {

  qDebug() << " Thread started";

   socket = new QTcpSocket() ;

   if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor))

   emit error(socket->error());

   return;

connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()),   Qt::DirectConnection);

connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));


    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Client connected";

     exec();
   }


void mythread::readyRead()

{
  QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();

  qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Data in: " << Data;

  socket->write(Data);
}



void mythread::disconnected()
{
  qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Disconnected";

  socket->deleteLater();

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Does `myserver.h` have a `void myserver::incomingConnections(qintptr socketDescriptor)` ?

Comment: yes I wrote it. protected:

    void incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor);

Comment: Is it `incomingConnection` or `incomingConnections`?

Comment: Oh..you right ..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you misspell the implementation method as:

```
incomingConnections
```

When you declared it in the header as:

```
incomingConnection
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Check incomingconnection spelling and capital and small letter combination, if you declare incomingComing then it should be incomingConnection or if incomingconnection then incomingconnection